# Tkinter how to bind to shift+tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I'm trying to bind the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> keys, but I can't seem to get it to work. The widget I'm binding to is an `Entry` widget.

I've tried binding the keys with `widget.bind('<Shift_Tab>', func)`, but I get an error message saying:

> File "/usr/lib64/python3.8/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1337, in
>   _bind self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
>   _tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "Shift_Tab"

---

## Update

I'm still having a problem detecting <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. Here is my test code. **My OS is Linux.** The <kbd>tab</kbd> key works, just not <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. Seems like a simple problem to solve, so I must be going about it wrong?

I'm trying to tab between columns in a `Treeview` that I have overlaid widgets on a row to simulate inline editing. There can be only one active widget on a line. I keep track of what column I'm in and *when the user presses <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>TAB</kbd>, I remove the current widget and display a new widget in the corresponding column.*

Here is a [link](https://github.com/unodan/TkInter-Treeview-Example-Demo) to the complete project:

The project is in one file and has no imports.

*The code below is my attempt and it doesn't work.*

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.title('Default Demo')
        self.geometry('420x200')

        wdg = ttk.Entry(self)
        wdg.grid()

        def tab(_):
            print('Tab pressed.')

        def shift_tab(_):
            print('Shift tab pressed.')

        wdg.bind('<Tab>', tab)
        wdg.bind('<Control-ISO_Left_Tab>', shift_tab)


def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you want `shift+tab`, then the event should be `<Shift-ISO_Left_Tab>` instead of `<Control-ISO_Left_Tab>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a direct answer and too long for a comment.

You can solve your question by yourself with a simple trick, bind `<Key>` to a function, and print the key event argument passed to the `bind` function where you can see which key is pressed or not. Try multiple combinations of keys to see what is the `state` and what is their `keysym` or `keycode`.

```py
import tkinter as tk

def key_press(evt):
    print(evt)

root = tk.Tk()
root.bind("<Key>", key_press)
root.mainloop()
```

It will output the following for pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> combo on macOS.

```py
<KeyPress event state=Shift keysym=Tab keycode=3145753 char='\x19' x=-5 y=-50>
```

Where,

- **`state=Shift`** means a key event's state is on <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>.
- **`keysym=Tab`** means tab key is pressed. If we just press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, the `keysym` will be Shift_L or Shift_R *(shows Shift_L for both shift keys on mac).*
- **`keycode`** is an unique code for each key even for different key combos for example keycode for *Left Shift* is `131330` and keycode for <kbd>TAB</kbd> is `3145737` but when <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> is pressed the code is not the same to either, it is `3145753`. *(I'm not sure if these are the same code for every os but one can figure it out by printing them to the console)*
- *Also, see all the [event attributes.](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Event-class.html)*

Though bind `'<Shift-Tab>'` key combination works well on Mac, it can also be used like so...

```py
def key_press(evt):
    if evt.keycode==3145753:
        print('Shift+Tab is pressed')
```

Answer (score 6):

The following code (in python 2.7.6) should make it clear:
I hope this reference works for you

```
from Tkinter import *

def key(event=None):
    print 'You pressed Ctrl+Shift+Tab'

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.focus_set()
frame.bind('<Control-Shift-KeyPress-Tab>', key)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

EDIT: The above works well for Windows and Mac. For Linux, use

```
'<Control-ISO_Left_Tab>'.
```

Comment: for Linux use what?

Comment: I tried that on Linux and it does not work. The call back never happens.

Comment: from Tkinter import *

def proof(event=None):
    print 'ping'

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, height=100, width=100)
frame.focus_set()
frame.bind('<Control-Shift-KeyPress-U>', proof)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()

Comment: I'm binding to an entry widget not a fame, maybe that's why?

Comment: @DanielHuckson, Please correct me if I am wrong, but this answer doesn't contain a reputable source as a citation. In your bounty description, you say you are looking for *an answer from a reputable source*.

Comment: i'm not reputable source? if you are not agree, it is ok, but what is your problem? be kind at least

Comment: You are equally important as anyone else on this site :-). But I think the original poster of this question wants to bind `Shift` + `Key` whereas in your answer you are using `Control` key as well, You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62335616/edit) your post and correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for Linux users that want to bind `Shift+Tab`.

```
def press(e):
        print('Shift+Tab is pressed')

widget.bind('<ISO_Left_Tab>',press)
```